# scan aws lambda function on dynamodb using an index

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

```
'use strict'
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1"});

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: "2012-10-08"});
const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: "us-east-1"});
const params = 
{
    TableName: "Music",
    ConsistentRead: true,
    IndexName: "Genre-index",
    FilterExpression: "Genre = :Genre",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: 
    {
        ":Genre": "Rock"
    },
    Limit: 10
}
try 
{
    const data = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();
    console.log(data);
} catch (err)  
{
    console.log(err);
}
```

}

I am trying to make a lambda function in AWS and I have followed some tutorials but none of them touch on the topic of scanning a dynamodb table by an index. The code above is what I have doctored so far. Does anyone know how make this work? I am using the AWS api gateway to invoke this function, I also am wondering how it returns a list. I am a member of a team project and the website is coded in angular. We have figured out the GetItem and PutItem api calls and I just mainly need scan to work. Also, I am using scan because I need to search for genre of album titles and it is not a primary key or sort key.

Response when I test in Lambda:

```
START RequestId: 2581086d-06e1-49b0-80bc-619179b47fa5 Version: $LATEST
2020-11-04T20:19:40.333Z    2581086d-06e1-49b0-80bc-619179b47fa5    INFO     
ValidationException: Consistent reads are not supported on global secondary 
indexes
at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws- 
sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)
at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws- 
sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws- 
sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws- 
sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws- 
sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws- 
sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws- 
sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws- 
sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
code: 'ValidationException',
time: 2020-11-04T20:19:40.216Z,
requestId: '6FN6892H2KHUUK1P9OSSK0USTFVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',
statusCode: 400,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 21.095705138721677
}
END RequestId: 2581086d-06e1-49b0-80bc-619179b47fa5
REPORT RequestId: 2581086d-06e1-49b0-80bc-619179b47fa5  Duration: 893.02 ms  
Billed Duration: 900 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 87 MB  Init 
Duration: 381.56 ms
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Scan always scans the whole table, you're just filtering out some of the results.

Comment: I added the response when testing in lambda ^^^